# jquery Find out which button was clicked in AJAX posting

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have a form with 2 buttons, Confirm & Delete. I am posting a hidden input element ID. When Confirm is clicked, an action will be taken by using the element ID. If Delete is clicked, an entry in DB with the element ID is deleted. Now, the issue is when I do a `print_r($_POST); exit();`, it gives me the input element ID correctly. But it does NOT tell me which button was clicked. Is there a way to find out which button was exactly clicked in a single form? Both the buttons need to exist in the same form.

Here's my code that I tried:

**jQuery**

```
    var dataString = $('#form_confirm_delete').serialize();

    $.ajax({

              type: "POST",
              url: "ajaxpage.php",
              data: dataString,
              dataType: 'json',
              cache: false,       
              success: (function(response) 
                {
                    alert('Yes');
                })

         });
```

**PHP page (ajaxpage.php):**

```
<?php print_r($_POST); exit(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something like this

```
url: "ajaxpage.php?button="+id,

$("#BUTTON1").click(function(){
var url="ajaxpage.php?button="+this.id,
"
})
```

and in server side you can get that variable

or you can use post variable

```
var id=this.id;
$.ajax({

              type: "POST",
              url: "ajaxpage.php",
              data:{"dataString": dataString,"id":id},
              dataType: 'json',
              cache: false,       
              success: (function(response) 
                {
                    alert('Yes');
                })
           // you can use this variable id server-side     
         });
```

Comment: This solution, by far, seems to be the most easiest and simple way to do what I was trying, with minimal addition of new code. I totally forgot that we can capture the ID of the clicked button & send it via the dataString. Thank you very much for your solution, it worked excellent!

Answer (score 3):

You could have a hidden input for the clicked button

When one of your two buttons is clicked

get the value of the clicked button for instance delete

```
<button id="deleteButton" value="delete">Delete</button>
```

and store the value of the clicked button in  a variable like

```
$("#deleteButton").click(function(){
  var thebuttonclicked =$(this).attr("value");
```

then set the value of the hidden field

```
$('input[name=theclicked]').val(thebuttonclicked);
```

when submitted,you could get the post with the name theclicked.
I think that this method is better even if http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2 the clicked button is submitted, jquery serialize does not include the clicked button.For more on serialize you could refer to http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: +1 That would also be an alternate way of doing what I was trying to do. My requirement was to not add any more input elements and avoid writing more code to populate the data. So I had to go with @jhonraymos solution. But I believe that in cases where addition of new elements to the form is allowed, your solution can also be used. Thanks for posting the alternate.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen for both buttons doing:

```
$( '#delete_button' ).click(function(){
     submitForm( 'delete' );
}); 

$( '#submit_button' ).click(function(){
     submitForm( 'submit' );
});
```

And then pass your paramater in a single function:

```
function submitForm( type ){

    var dataString = $('#form_confirm_delete').serialize();
    dataString += "&type=" + type; 
    $.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: "ajaxpage.php",
          data: dataString,
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,       
          success: (function(response) 
            {
                alert('Yes');
            })

     });
}
```

Comment: +1 That would be a good alternate way of doing what I was trying to do. Just wanted to make sure that I edit as less code as possible, so I had to go with @jhonraymos solution. Thanks for posting the alternate.